# Compare three integers

Tags: ruby

I have three integers, and I need to find the highest value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way would be to put them into an Array, then you can use .max on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as it is:

```
[x, y, z].max
```

Example:

```
x, y, z = 1, 7, 3

[x, y, z].max
=> 7

[x, y, z].min
=> 1
```